# How to tidy mixed variables and observations with R?

Tags: r, dataset, tidyr

I cannot find any solution for tidying a dataset I imported from a html table. This one combines both observations and variables as rows (the nightmare).

it looks like this :

```
    w <- c(5,"A",1,2)
x <- c(5,"B",3,4)
y <- c(10,"A",5,6)
z <- c(10,"B",7,8)

df <- data.frame(w,x,y,z)

rownames(df) <- c("temp","cat","obs1", "obs2")
colnames(df) <- NA

df

temp  5  5 10 10
cat   A  B  A  B
obs1  1  3  5  7
obs2  2  4  6  8
```

variables are temp and cat while obs1 and obs2 are observations. What I'm trying to obtain is :

```
obs   temp cat value
obs1  5    A   1  
obs1  5    B   3  
obs2  5    A   2  
obs2  5    B   4  
obs1  10   A   5  
obs1  10   B   6  
obs2  10   A   7  
obs2  10   B   8
```

I messed around with `gather()`and `spread()`but nothing ...

Any suggestion ?

thank you  !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just transpose it ?

```
library(tidyverse)
w <- c(5,"A",1,2)
x <- c(5,"B",3,4)
y <- c(10,"A",5,6)
z <- c(10,"B",7,8)
df <- data.frame(w,x,y,z)

rownames(df) <- c("temp","cat","obs1", "obs2")
colnames(df) <- NA

t(df) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  gather(key = "k", value = "value", "obs1", "obs2") %>% 
  select(-k) %>% 
  arrange(desc(temp))

  temp cat value
1    5   A     1
2    5   B     3
3    5   A     2
4    5   B     4
5   10   A     5
6   10   B     7
7   10   A     6
8   10   B     8
```

Comment: Thank you, this -almost does the trick ! It still lacks the `obs` column which is essential in my case. So I removed `select(-k)` !

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `data.table`. `df3` is the final output.

```
library(data.table)

new_col <- rownames(df)      # Save row names as the new column name
df2 <- transpose(df)         # Transpose the data frame
names(df2) <- new_col        # Assign the column name
setDT(df2)                   # Convert to data.table

# Perform the transformation
df3 <- melt(df2, measure.vars = c("obs1", "obs2"), 
            variable.name = "obs")[
  order(-temp, obs), .(obs, temp, cat, value)
]

# Print df3
df3
#     obs temp cat value
# 1: obs1    5   A     1
# 2: obs1    5   B     3
# 3: obs2    5   A     2
# 4: obs2    5   B     4
# 5: obs1   10   A     5
# 6: obs1   10   B     7
# 7: obs2   10   A     6
# 8: obs2   10   B     8
```